# How many records can be loaded into Salesforce using Apex Data Loader in one go?

Tags: csv, salesforce, apex-code, loader

We have to insert thousands of record into Salesforce using Apex Data Loader. We use csv files to load data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there's no real limit in the Data Loader itself. From the **[Data Loader guide](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)**:

> Use the Data Loader when: You need to
>   load 50,000 to 5,000,000 records. If
>   you need to load more than 5,000,000
>   records, we recommend you work with a
>   Salesforce.com partner.

Really check out the PDF, especially for the (little) info about "bulk API" if the speed of normal loading is insufficient for you and you have already tweaked the number of records sent in one batch (by default 100 or 200 I think).

And if the **[bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynchpre/api_bulk.pdf)** looks too complex, you can always use very simple parallelization of the task - one username can have up to 4 sessions open, so you could invoke Data Loader 4 times with 1/4 of original CSV.

Comment: Hi @eyescream. Would you kindly elaborate more on "you can always use very simple parallelization of the task - one username can have up to 4 sessions open, so you could invoke Data Loader 4 times with 1/4 of original CSV"? Thanks.

Comment: @MnZ - DataLoader is a simple program, you can have more than 1 copy running at the same time. So if you need to load a big file that has no dependencies between the rows you could cut it into few pieces (just copy the header row!) and upload in parallel. Check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/implementation_considerations.htm for example - it doesn't list 4 as a limit (it seems they changed it to reuse same session id... remember that this answer is 4 years old :P).

Comment: I once had to run a data migration to SF. We loaded fairly small amount of related data (Accounts, Contacts, Opps), had to go in the right order. But we also had some unrelated reference data (Products, lookup tables, info which phone numbers are available / taken; this was for a telecom). So one "thread" of Data Loader was uploading the 1M + of phone numbers while other "threads" were uploading Accounts etc. In the end the phone numbers took longest to load anyway (5h I think) but at least it was on 4 "threads" instead of sequential run that locks your machine for 20h and you can't go home...

Answer (score 0):

[Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Apex_Data_Loader) definitely works fine with thousands of records. I have a setup that does this on a daily basis.

One good feature of the Data Loader is the ability to import data from, or export data to, a database. This way, you can avoid having to use CSV files (assuming that your data is available in a database).

By using a database as the source of your data, you can implement incremental loads. The Data Loader remembers the last time it ran, so you can write a database query that extracts all records added/changed since the last Data Loader run. That way, you won't need to load the complete dataset each time.

Also, Data Loader can perform an "Upsert", which combines an INSERT and UPDATE. That means you can load new records and existing records at the same time, with the existing records simply being updated. That's a feature not normally available in SQL situations.